# Determine whether the two sheeted hyperboloid $x^2-y^2-z^2=1$ is connected

Tags: general-topology

It is disconnected right? Just looking at the graph, there is a gap between the two sheets so it should be easy to write the set of points on the surface as the union of two open, disjoint, non-empty sets $A$ & $B$. However I cant seem to actually write down two such sets, I think Im missing something trivial:

So the gap between the two sheets is when $-1 \lt x \lt 1$ so the we should split the region into two somewhere here. 
If say I let $A=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb {R^3} : x^2-y^2-z^2=1, x\gt 1\} $, Then I miss the point $(1,0,0)$ which is on the surface. But if I let $A=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb {R^3} : x^2-y^2-z^2=1, x\ge 1\} $ then Im pretty sure this is not an open set anymore. 
This is where I am confused, any help appreciated.

Comment: I have changed "paraboloid" into "hyperboloid" in the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solve with respect to $x$:
$$
x=\pm\sqrt{1+y^2+z^2}
$$
that should give the idea: let $H$ be the hyperboloid and consider
$$
H_+=H\cap\{(x,y,z):x>0\},\quad
H_-=H\cap\{(x,y,z):x<0\}.
$$

Comment: Since H does not contain any points where $0\lt x\lt1$ is your $H_+$ not the same as my second choice for $A$ ?

Comment: @ConnorBishop: Yes, but egreg's description shows that it is open, which you had trouble seeing using your description.

Comment: Sorry I am still missing something, egreg's $H_+$ contains the point $(1,0,0)$ right? but wont any open ball centered around $(1,0,0)$ contain points not in $H_+$ ?

Comment: @ConnorBishop *Any* open ball around a point of the hyperboloid contains points not in $H$.

Comment: If $(x,y,z)$ is in the open ball of radius $1$ about $(1,0,0)$ then $x>0$ so $(x,y,z)\in H_+.$  Neither of the choices for  $ A (x>1$ or $ x\geq 1)$ is egreg's $H_+ (x>0).$

Comment: I just cant see how $H_+$ is an open set, I can see that $\{(x,y,z):x\gt 0\}$ is open, but then when you intersect with $H$ surely you get a set which is not fully open

Comment: @ConnorBishop You want *relatively open* subsets of $H$.

Comment: thats what i missing! thanks